# Add proguard enabled apk later in play store

Tags: android

I wan to  add android apk in google play without pro-guard and after some releases build with pro-guard enabled.
Can we add android apk in google play without pro-guard and after some releases can we add build with pro-guard enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The Play Store has no idea if proguard is used or not.  The only restrictions on future builds uploaded to the Play Store is that you must sign with the same key, and you must increase the version number in the manifest/gradle.